# Getting Authentication For NeverBounce

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to use NeverBounce to verify an email address that is entered in a form. On their documentation it says that first I need to get a request for an access token and they give the following command to show you how to do it:

```
curl -X POST -u <API USERNAME>:<API SECRET KEY> https://api.neverbounce.com/v3/access_token\
-d grant_type=client_credentials\
-d scope=basic+user
```

How would I write a PHP script that does this please?

Comment: Rather than use cUrl etc. I suggest that you use: [This package provides convenient methods to integrate the NeverBounce API into your project.](https://github.com/NeverBounce/NeverBounceAPI-PHP). It does all the hard work for you.

Comment: That would definitely be easier and I did look at that but unfortunately I have to use cURL

Comment: just curious - why cant you use that package?  Ok, if you look through the source code of that link then you can see exactly what options you need to use and how to do it. see: [NB_Curl](https://github.com/NeverBounce/NeverBounceAPI-PHP/blob/master/src/api/NB_Curl.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://api.neverbounce.com/v3/access_token');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache',
  'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'authorization' => 'Basic <YOUR ENCODED STRING>'
));

$request->setContentType('application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$request->setPostFields(array(
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
  'scope' => 'basic user'
));

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

For generating value of authorization key construct a string as USERNAME:SECRETKEY and encode this value.